# Cant create new Active Directory Group. C# and LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

[image: Who can explain that? What am I doing wrong? I check existence of the group before and it sais, that the group does not exist.]

I use following parameters:

```
groupName="S_DE_Test1" 

ouPath="OU=Miscellaneous,OU=VCS_Groups,DC=vcs,DC=de"

accountName = "mysurename"
```

`username`  and `password` are globally defined

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: To me, since the error is "The object already exists" - it looks like the group with the sAMAccountName=accountName already exists. Please check in your DC whether this group exists any where in the entire domain. Also, if it is possible for you to try with another sAMAccountName, this would clear any confusion. Please let me know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I decommented the line  //group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = accountName; And then it did not throw the error and added the group. But how can I set the sAMAccountname now?  It must contain my accountname, mustn't it?

Comment: jwilleke see the picture. The error says: "The object already exists."

Comment: I informed myself and now I understand it. The sAMAccountname is also the Groupname and the "groupName" is only the displayname. 
Thanks a lot Am_I_Helpful, you helped me :D